# Error al clonar repositorio privado en GitHub

Tags: git, github

Estoy teniendo problemas al clonar un repositorio desde GitHub. el error es el que se muestra en la imagen, asociado a que ya no esta vigente el uso de credenciales.

Esto no me ocurre en una portátil que me brindo la empresa, ya que desde ahí puedo clonar repositorios sin problema alguno mediante https.

[image: error que se genera]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema es que no tienes ningún software de autenticación para poder descargar desde github.

Github exige que se utilice un usuario y contraseña para poder clonar repositorios, por lo que necesitarás disponer en el equipo de algún software de autenticación adecuado.

Si te fijas, en el mensaje de error te da un enlace informativo:

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls

Allí te sugiere que utilices el software que encontrarás en:

https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/README.md

Si instalas ese programa, cuando quieras clonar el repositorio (si no estás autentificado) te pedirá los datos de conexión y podrás hacerlo sin problemas.

Answer (score 1):

primero de todo, siempre que puedas intenta **no** añadir capturas a la pregunta y copia y pega el error directamente. Así haces la vida más fácil a los que te van a intentar ayudar.

Segundo, ¿has leído [el post](https://docs.github.com/es/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories) en la url que te dice el error? porque ahí explica perfectamente lo que te pasa.

Github ha cambiado como se hace la autenticación, ahora no puedes usar directamente la contraseña de tu cuenta, tienes que [primero generar un `Access token`](https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) asignarle los permisos que necesites y luego usarlo en vez de la contraseña de la cuenta.